# Not determining what the largest variable is properly

Tags: javascript

I have re written my code slightly for a cleaner more efficient code, and it it not determining the largest variable, it is just setting it to the first variable ran now. It also stopped inserting the variable value into the test spans I have set up.

http://www.sprayfoamsys.com/cmsdev/index.php?page=rig-constructor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var sec1=0;
        var sec2=0;
        var sec3=0;

        function secVar(){
            if(sec1) {
                sec1++;
                document.getElementById('sec1text').innerHTML = sec1;
            }
            if(sec2) {
                sec2++;
                document.getElementById('sec2text').innerHTML = sec2;
            }
            if(sec3) {
                sec3++;
                document.getElementById('sec3text').innerHTML = sec3;
            }

            largest = Math.max(sec1, sec2, sec3);
            if (largest === sec1) {
              //a
            } else if (largest === sec2) {
              //b
            } else if (largest === sec3) {
              //c
            }
            switch (largest) {
              case sec1:
                document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test1';
                break;
              case sec2:
                document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test2';
                break;
              case sec3:
                document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test3';
                break;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The questions have the `secVar(sec1);`, `secVar(sec2);`, `secVar(sec3);` depending on the question that they answer onclick.

The previous code I had looked like this below. But was still not determining the largest variable correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var sec1=0;
        var sec2=0;
        var sec3=0;

        function sec1Var(){
        sec1++;
        document.getElementById('sec1text').innerHTML = sec1;
        }

        function sec2Var(){
        sec2++;
        document.getElementById('sec2text').innerHTML = sec2;
        }

        function sec3Var(){
        sec3++;
        document.getElementById('sec3text').innerHTML = sec3;
        }

        largest = Math.max(sec1, sec2, sec3);

        function largestVar(){
            if (largest === sec1) {
              //a
            } else if (largest === sec2) {
              //b
            } else if (largest === sec3) {
              //c
            }

            switch (largest) {
              case sec1:
                document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test1';
                break;
              case sec2:
                document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test2';
                break;
              case sec3:
                document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test3';
                break;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

What is causing it not to work?

Comment: yes, what is causing it not to work?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, can you elaborate? Also can you put the text beside your radio buttons into labels?

Comment: All of your variables are set to 0.  So they are all equal.  You are referencing sec1, sec2, sec3 in your function but none of those variables exist within the scope of the function and they have not been passed to the function via parameters.

Comment: So if I am understanding you correctly, the global functions have to be defined locally as well?

Comment: Jrod, I haven't checked, but assuming that's a good answer, *answer* the question instead of leaving a comment

Comment: BrettAdamsGA, there is nothing wrong with the scope of the variables, you should not "defined them locally as well".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I happen to have seen your previous question about the same topic)

I think you've combined two different ideas: determining the largest value and determining the variable whose value is the largest.  You're looking for something like the following:

```
function largestVar(){
    if (sec1 >= sec2 && sec1 >= sec3) {
        //a
        document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test1';
    } else if (sec2 >= sec1 && sec2 >= sec3) {
        //b
        document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test2';
    } else {
        //c
        document.getElementById('rig').innerHTML = 'Test3';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is still giving me Test1 every time I try even when I answer in favor of test2 or test3.